# jQuery File Upload with AngularJS causes high CPU usage

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

We are using the jQuery file upload plugin in AngularJS and noticed that a file upload causes constantly high CPU usage in the browser, even after the upload finished. Deleting the uploaded item doesn't help.

See the example here:

https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html

When you select an image and click the start upload button the CPU usage will go up and stay up even though the upload finished.

Comment: This sounds like a support issue for the library, not a stack overflow question

Comment: I would have opened an issue if the repo would support that... https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload#support

Comment: did u get any answers?

Comment: I'd be interested to know if you resolved this.  I'm getting high CPU usage too, which can be worked around by ramping up VM resources (not ideal).  I wonder why processing the upload is so CPU and RAM intensive?

Also, there's a 1 minute delay after uploading 2gb+ files.. Are you experiencing this?

Comment: @BSUK Sorry no luck. We gave up at some point.